# ajax won't fire on subsequent modal forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I've got this index of items listed out on a page, and on this page each item has a link that pops open a unique modal.  in this modal i have a :username text field and a corresponding ajax call so when you type @username the usernames of your friends pop up (novel idea, right?).  Anyway, it only works for the first item-link-modal combo, then the subsequent item/link/modal combos don't function.  here's where i'm stuck, any help greatly appreciated:

modal partial:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pirateinvite-<%= x.id %>" tabindex="-1" 
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pirateinviteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="pirateinviteLabel">Invite a friend</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    blah blah

    <%= form_for @invitations, :url => invitations_path, :method => 'create', remote: true do |b| %>

    <div class="form-group"><center>
      <b><%= b.label :username, 'Invite by username:' %></b></center>
      <%= b.text_area :username, rows: 1, class: 'form-control', required: true, placeholder: "@user1 @user2" %>
      <%= b.hidden_field :event_id, :value => x.id %>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
    <%= b.submit 'Send an Invite!', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm align-self-center' %>
  <% end %></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

invitations.coffee

```
class @Invitation

@add_atwho = ->
$('#invitation_username').atwho
  at: '@'
  displayTpl:"<li class='mention-item' data-value='(${image},${name})'><img src=${image}>@${name}</li>",
  callbacks: remoteFilter: (query, callback) ->
    if (query.length < 1)
      return false
    else
      $.getJSON '/mentionsy', { q: query }, (data) ->
        callback data

jQuery ->
Invitation.add_atwho()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to make each textarea id in the modals unique by changing it to `<%= b.text_area :username, id: "invitation_username_#{+ x.id}", rows: 1, role: "textarea", class: 'form-control', required: true, placeholder: "@user1 @user2" %>`

Needed to change atwho listener to listen for all of those unique text areas like so:  `$('textarea[id^=invitation_username_]').atwho`